# How to add a gradient to buttons in android through xml?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, button, colors

I cannot figure out why this code will not work. Can anyone help? I am trying to get the button to use a custom color titled 'greenstart' and 'greenend'. The colors have been created in the res/value/string.xml file. I have looked at similar questions but either they were left unanswered, unclear, or the solution did not work. Thanks in advance.

XML FILE SAMPLE:

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/mycollection"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_weight="1" >

   <Gradient
      android:angle="270"
      android:endColor="@color/greenstart"
      android:startColor="@color/greenend" >
   </Gradient>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Create a new xml file and put it in drawable and then add it to button as background

**gradient.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
    <!--  Gradient Bg for listrow -->
   <gradient
      android:startColor="#f1f1f2"
      android:centerColor="#e7e7e8"
      android:endColor="#cfcfcf"
      android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

**layout.xml**

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:text="Übernehmen" >
```

Comment: How would do I call it as the button backgroud? "android:background="@?"

Comment: Note that the `<shape>` isn't necessary. I got the same results just creating the `<gradient>`, without any `<shape>` around it.

Answer (score 19):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#70c656" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#53933f" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#70c656"
                android:endColor="#53933f"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#53933f" />
            <corners
                android:radius="4dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 9):

So here we go with the gradient. As above @Dusean Singh said. If you will use an angle 270 then your gradient will start from top to down : TOP -> Center -> bottom

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FF0000"
        android:centerColor="#00FF00"
        android:endColor="#0000FF"
        android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

[image]

If you will use an angle 360 then your gradient will start from left to right : Left -> Center -> Right

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <!--  Gradient Bg for listrow -->
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FF0000"
        android:centerColor="#00FF00"
        android:endColor="#0000FF"
        android:angle="360" />
</shape>
```

[image]

Here we go with the effect. and how to apply the same on button

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/design_bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">
    <Button
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Find"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_button"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="Match"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_button"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: SufiyanAnsari I tried this method in `AndroidX` but this is not work in androidx. Any other method for androidx to add a gradient background to the button?

Comment: @SufiyanAnsari try app:backgroundTint="@null"

Answer (score 4):

Create `gradient.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
      android:angle="270"
      android:endColor="@color/greenstart"
      android:startColor="@color/greenend" />

</shape>
```