# Creating Xamarin button with gradient colour and curved edges

Tags: xamarin.android

I have a xamarin Android button with curved edges (Border radius). There I want to make colour as gradient.

If I try to make it by painting the canvas (as a custom renderer)  it will disappear curved edges as follows by overriding the ButtonRenderer's DispatchDraw function.

```
protected override void DispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    var gradient = new Android.Graphics.LinearGradient(0, 0, Width, Height,
        this.StartColor.ToAndroid(),
        this.EndColor.ToAndroid(),
        Android.Graphics.Shader.TileMode.Clamp);
    var paint = new Android.Graphics.Paint()
    {
        Dither = true,
    };
    paint.SetShader(gradient);
    canvas.DrawPaint(paint);
    base.DispatchDraw(canvas);
}
```

With the above code it button will disappear the curved edges.  Before this code I was settings the color with the background property. With that property I can see the curved edges but not with the above code.

So my assumption is if I can set the gradient color for the background color property of the button this will work, unfortunately I couldn't find a way to do it.

Could someone help me to achieve this?

Comment: show us what exactly do you want

Comment: @G.hakim thanks for comment, I just updated the question with more information.

Comment: Share an image of what you want if possible

Comment: http://www.stickpng.com/img/icons-logos-emojis/empty-buttons/light-blue-rounded-button places find above blue colour button

Comment: check this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166559/how-to-add-a-gradient-to-buttons-in-android-through-xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find XML to be more understandable so, i would do something like this:

**Gradient.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item>
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <!--make a gradient background-->
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:startColor="#556B2F"
        android:endColor="#BDB76B"
        android:centerColor="#ffffff"
        android:angle="90"
        android:gradientRadius="90"
        />
    <!--apply a border around button-->
    <stroke android:color="#006400" android:width="2dp" />
    <!-- make the button corners rounded-->
    <corners android:radius="25dp"/>
</shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Use it like this in your button xml :

```
android:background="@drawable/Gradient"
```

Or in C# code like this:

```
 _button.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.Gradient);
```

Comment: is there a way that I can define multiple gradients in the same xml ?

Comment: well to my extent of knowledge in android i don't think you can do that but you can surf a little to find out if it is possible and in case it is let me know aswell