# how to do round corner of a button in Xamarin android using visual studio 2017

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

Hi i am not able to find drawable folder in VS 2017, So my question is where i can place my XML file "RoundShapeBtn.xml" as drawable for making my button with round corner.

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">   
  <solid android:color="#6E6E6E"/> <!-- this one is ths color of the Rounded Button -->
  <corners
   android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
   android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
   android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
   android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Check my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50075896/7462031

Comment: @G.hakim actually i am not able to find drawable folder in visual studio 2017

Comment: use mipmap in place of drawable and it will work, by that i mean where ever there is drawable use mipmap instead

Comment: @G.hakim, Thanks it is working..