# Android: Gradient FAB background

Tags: android, android-layout, gradient, floating-action-button

Can someone share how to implement a gradient background to a floating action button ?

I want to achieve something like that:

[image: Gradient FAB]

I tried to use the drawable below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <gradient
            android:type="linear"
            android:angle="0"
            android:startColor="#f6ee19"
            android:endColor="#115ede" />
    </shape>

</item>
<item android:gravity="center"
    >
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_close_accent"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal" />

</item>
```

Then in my activity i set android:src to this drawable but it didn't work

I also tried to set android:backgroundTint and android:background but these didn't work too.

Can someone please help?

Comment: You need to use the `app` namespace not the `android` namespace. See here: [How to change FAB background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34606766/how-to-change-fab-background-color)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166559/how-to-add-a-gradient-to-buttons-in-android-through-xml

Comment: @Anmol Can you please read my question carefully ?

Comment: @ChrisStillwell I just tried it, still doesn't work.

Comment: @CodeWithVikas android:background is not working for me. Have you tried this code on a FAB ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried many solution's but was not able to change the background where i can use drawable as resource.

So tried to use below might be helpful in your case.

## Layout.xml

```
...
...
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/fab_scr"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="0dp" />
...
...
```

I am setting `android:src` to a drawable and removing background(i.e transparent)

## fab_src.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#38260D" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="20dp"
                android:left="20dp"
                android:right="20dp"
                android:top="20dp" />
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="8dip"
                android:bottomRightRadius="8dip"
                android:topLeftRadius="8dip"
                android:topRightRadius="8dip" />

            <gradient
                android:angle="45"
                android:centerX="50"
                android:centerY="50"
                android:endColor="#B9FFA6"
                android:gradientRadius="100"
                android:startColor="#EB77FF"
                android:type="linear" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@android:color/white" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="90"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="-90">
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="@android:color/white" />

            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

#### Result:

[image: SS]

> Note:
>   trying to find a way to remove the outer ring(yellow is you find a way do comment i will improve the answer)

Comment: It's not working. I took your code like it is exactly but it renders a black FAB with no icon...

Comment: android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"  this is important part of code.

Comment: Set app:borderWidth="0dp" to remove outer black ring