# Gradient color not applied to button in android studio

Tags: android

I have created a gradient_file.xml in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />

    <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/white"
        android:endColor="@color/black"
        android:angle="45"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

I have applied it to button in my layout

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_file"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.243" />
```

This is the result i am getting:

[image]

The color should be different. i have rebuild the project but the color does not change in preview nor in emulator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a gradient to buttons in android through xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166559/how-to-add-a-gradient-to-buttons-in-android-through-xml)

Comment: No, As you can see i am already doing what your solution is doing but i am not getting any result. The color of button is not changing

Comment: please share me the style and theme used in the project

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Background Drawable Not Working in Button Since Android Studio 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64722733/android-background-drawable-not-working-in-button-since-android-studio-4-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is getting overwritten by the colors in themes.xml file.  Go to your themes.xml file (in res/values/themes) and replace

```
 <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
```

with

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@null</item>
```

to see your gradient work.

**EDIT**: I'm not sure why this is... could be a bug in newer android studio versions?  But I was able to get your button gradient working with this solution

Comment: Thanks it worked. Yes you are right. My color scheme should override the scheme provided by default.

Comment: Can you tell me another way which wont require my to change my theme and have this work?

Comment: Because the views that use that primary-color will lose that color. so it there another way?

Comment: @M.Ahmed - I wish I knew.  Like I mentioned I'm not sure why this is happening and seems to be an issue in newer versions of android studio from what I can tell.

Answer (score 6):

In themes.xml, change

```
<style name="Theme.YourApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="Theme.YourApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

Then the submitted drawable will work!

Comment: It's AppCompat, not AppCompact. (fixed it for you)

Answer (score 5):

I resolved this issue like this in button attributes:

```
app:backgroundTint="@null"
```

Answer (score 0):

I also resolved this issue by using this.
Go to themes.xml
and change color primary by this,
@null